# Creating pointer using #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to create pointer using `#define`?
Something like this:

```
#define *HEY
```

I'll use it for something like this:

```
#define *HEY 2
...
int *s=HEY;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "create pointer"? Can you show how would you USE this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that even if is was possible?

Comment: You should avoid obfuscating code like this, as it will cause headaches down the line.  Always try to make your code as self-documenting as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, asterisks aren't allowed in `#define` macro names.

Your example variable declaration wouldn't work anyway, because it doesn't contain the text `*HEY`, it only contains `HEY`, which doesn't match the defined macro name.

What's that code intended to do?  Make a pointer that points to the number 2?

Comment: it was just something i was doing, i was thinking using #define instead of declaring a variable

Comment: #define 's NEVER create any variables. They provide us with symbolic constants such dat if we do #define AA 2 , wherever in the code we write AA , while compilation , it is replaced by 2. It is to be kept in mind that AA is not a variable and hence doing something like AA = 3 ; will cause an error.

Comment: So creating a pointer thus does not make sense as pointers store memory locations allocated during runtime. The values of the #define 's are parsed before running the program when no memory locations are available.

Answer (score 1):

defines are based completely on text replacement. They can only insert text everywhere you call the name. In your question you already made two mistakes.

You may not use * in the name of the macro
if you want to call a macro you have to call it with the same name you defined it
if * would have been legal, you sould also have called it with exactly that name *HEY

By the way. There is absolutely no secret functionality hidden somewhere in macro definitions.

```
#define HEY 2
```

simply replayces every HEY in your sourcecode with a 2 before compiling. Nothing else happens.
You can replace everything you want to replace, even single opening braces if you want to.

```
#define OPEN (
...
cout << 2 * OPEN 3 + 4 ) << endl;
```

should work, even if is pretty useless

Comment: i know what it does, im just saying instead of creating a variable is used `#define`